# Runtime error when deleting a dynamically allocated object

Tags: c++, runtime-error, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an abstract class named `Company`, a typedef `typedef Company* CompanyP;` and the following map:

```
map<string, CompanyP> companies;
```

When I add companies into the program it's using the `insert` and `make_pair` functions, like this:

```
companies.insert(make_pair(companyName, new Stock(...)));
```

(`Stock`'s base class is `Company`)

So as far as I understand the `second` part of the pair is holding a pointer to this object that i allocated using `new`, so I should be able to `delete` it in later part of the code.

So why when I get to the following code in a different function called 
`removeCompany`, I get a runtime error? (`compList` is an array of strings and holds the keys to all existing functions) :

```
// Delete the company and than delete the pointer from the map
cout << companies.find(compList[cmd - 1])->first << endl;
delete companies.find(compList[cmd-1])->second;
cout << "The company \"" << compList[cmd-1] << "\" has been removed." << endl;
companies.erase(compList[cmd - 1]);
```

I know that the key is correct using the first line with the `cout` command because it rightfully shows that the `find` function indeed finds the correct pair, but when the debugger gets to the delete command I get a runtime error `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)`.

I've looked into other questions but they were all examples of using the wrong pointers. Here i'm using a base class pointer that points on a derived class, could this be the problem?

Comment: Are the destructors virtual?

Comment: Is it possible for `cmd-1` to ever resolve to less than zero?  Thus `compList[cmd-1]` might be garbage.  And does it happen EVERY time, or only sometimes?

Comment: I didn't define any destructors and cmd-1 shows the correct pair so it's not less than zero.

Comment: You must defune a virtual destructir for the base class

Comment: Why? It will just be an empty function, I have no use for destructors.

Comment: Your class has no members that need to be destroyed?

Comment: *I didn't define any destructors* -- Thus the error.  Calling delete on a base class pointer that points to a derived class is undefined behavior if the base class does not have virtual destructor.

Comment: No. none of them were dynamically allocated.

Comment: So why are you calling `delete` on non-dynamically allocated objects?

Comment: @PanthersFan92 That does not matter. The destructor still needs to be called so the destructors of the automatic objects can be called.  If the derived class destructor is not called then you do not cleanup the object correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
I did dynamically allocate the object itself using `new` as explained in the question

Comment: @NathanOliver
I don't understand. Say I have a class called `base`, so I need to write `virtual ~Base() { ;}` and in every derived class use `~Base() { ; } // Override` ? Like this?

Isn't the default destructor defined by default if you don't implement it anyway?

Comment: @PanthersFan92 You just need to declare it in the base class like `virtual ~base(){}` or `virtual ~base() = default;`

Comment: If you want polymorphic deletion, you need a virtual destructor. Hard requirement. The linked duplicate contains a detailed explanation. It does not matter that you write not code in the destructor. The compiler does.

Comment: Good Link Cody, but I would add on to this for PanthersFan that even if you're not allocating anything with `new` in the base class OR the derived class, and only have "automatic" members, you still need the base and derived destructors to be virtual.  This is the point he seems to not understand and/or object to.

Comment: I understand now that I need to make them virtual, I don't understand how is that useful or why is it mandatory. I will check the link that Cody gave, thanks.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 It is mandatory because that's the way the language works.  Again, you are deleting a derived class object through a base class pointer.  The mechanism that is used in C++ to say "I'm not really a base, I'm a derived so start deleting me from the derived object" is to make the destructor virtual in the base class.